# Prime factorization of large numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, prime-factoring

I want to find the prime factorization of large numbers less than 10^12.
I got this code (in java):

```
public static List<Long> primeFactors(long numbers) {
        long n = numbers;
        List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for (long i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
            while (n % i == 0) {
                factors.add(i);
                n /= i;
            }
        }
        if (n > 1) {
            factors.add(n);
        }
        return factors;
    }
```

First of all what is the complexity of the above algorithm ??I am having difficulties finding it ??

Also it will be too slow for large numbers that are prime .

Is there are better algorithm , or else how to optimize this algo ??

Comment: For a single number, you won't get a lot better. You can do some precalculation, but that only makes sense if you need to do a lot of factorizations.

Comment: I'd look into the Pollards Rho algorithm. Your number range doesn't really require it, but it would probably be better.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Prime Factorization Program in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4273368/1164465)

Comment: @harold - I'm not sure that's Pollard's Rho. It looks like trial division from `2` to `SQRT(n)`. I believe the `SQRT(n)` is correct: the `n / i` is a bit confusing, but I believe the loop executes while `i^2 <= n`, which is equivalent to `i <= SQRT(n)`. The inner `while` looks like it will remove multiple prime factors. For example, if a number is a multiple of 4, it will add `2` to the list twice.

Comment: @noloader yes, it's trial division, that's why I recommended something else

Comment: @Wayne - "Is there are better algorithm". Take a look at the [Prime Pages](http://primes.utm.edu/) from UTM. Its got lots of neat little nuggets of information on primes and factoring.

Comment: @harold - my bad.... for some reason I thought I read "it looks like Pollard's Rho". Where are my glasses.....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to factorize *many* large numbers, then you might be better off first finding the prime numbers up to `sqrt(n)` (e.g. using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)). Then you have to check only whether those prime numbers are factors instead of testing all `i <= sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Even if I find all the prime numbers upto `sqrt(n)`, if i'm asked to count numbers whose prime factorization yields excatly `k` prime factors for `t` number of times, this approach will worsen in performance. Can you suggest something more efficient?

Answer (score 5):

The complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`. There is no sense in checking numbers after `sqrt(n)`.

This means that for `10^12`, it will take at most `1 000 000` iterations, which is not slow.

Comment: Precalculation of the primes of up to 10^6 will make it ~10 times as faster

Answer (score 5):

Factorising large numbers is hard problem which is partly why encryption algos use factors of large prime numbers to make the encryption difficult to crack.

```
public static void main(String... args)  {
    int nums = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        primeFactors(Long.MAX_VALUE - i);
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        if (time > 100e6)
            System.out.println((Long.MAX_VALUE-i) + " took "+time/1000000+" ms.");
    }
}

public static List<Long> primeFactors(long n) {
    List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<Long>();
    while (n % 2 == 0 && n > 0) {
        factors.add(2L);
        n /= 2;
    }

    for (long i = 3; i * i <= n; i+=2) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1)
        factors.add(n);

    return factors;
}
```

prints

```
9223372036854775806 took 3902 ms.
9223372036854775805 took 287 ms.
9223372036854775804 took 8356 ms.
9223372036854775797 took 9519 ms.
9223372036854775796 took 1507 ms.
9223372036854775794 took 111 ms.
9223372036854775788 took 184 ms.
```

If you replace Long.MAX_VALUE with 1000000000000L they all factorize under 20 ms.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this is why encryption algorithms rely on large prime numbers

Comment: No point in doing the optimizations yourself (it's the compiler's job). You can use `n % 2 == 0` and `n /= 2`, it will make the code more readable. An actual optimization would be to replace `i++` by `i += 2`, since you checked divisibility by 2 already. It could also produce better results to precompute `sqrt(n)` beforehand instead of doing `i*i` in every iteration (I've seen this having a large impact in C++ code)

Comment: Also, what's much more important, you should run your code with `-ea`: The assertion is wrong if the number has a prime factor that is larger than the square root: Try running `primeFactors(6)`. OP's code is at least correct :)

Comment: @NiklasB. I meant to do += 2 :|

Comment: I removed the assert, since it was still wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

A better algorithm might be the following for searching for primes (my java is rusty, so some tweaking will probably be needed to get it to compile).

```
if (number % 2)
   factors.append(2)
if (number % 3)
   factors.append(3)

for(int n = 0; n < sqrt(number)/6; n++)
{
   if (number % (6 * n + 1))
      factors.append(6 * n + 1);
   if (number % (6 * n - 1))
      factors.append(6 * n - 1);
}
```

Comment: not sure what this algorithm wants to achieve!

Comment: @Nuclearman Why are you dividing the number by 6 in "sqrt(number/6)"?

Comment: Fair point, looks like that should be outside of square root.

Comment: The conditions for appending factors seem complemented.