# Spreading out long numbers into prime factors

Tags: java, types, long-integer

I'd like to spread out big numbers into prime factors. To do that Im using my version of Sieve of Eratosthenes (Basically I'm keeping smallest prime factor of every number in range in an array)

```
        protected final static int PowOf2= 21;
        protected final static int[] Sieve = new int[(int) Math.pow(2,PowOf2)];
        protected final static int range = (int) Math.pow(2,PowOf2); //range of long types
        static int a=0; //counter


        public static void init(long n){
            for(int i=0; i<range-1; i++){
                Sieve[i]=i; //at first every number is equal to it's index
            }
            for(int i = 2; i*i <= range-1; i++) 
            {
                if (Sieve[i] == i){
                    for (int j = 2 * i ; j <= range-1; j += i)
                    {
                        Sieve[j] = i; //after that every number(index) has a smallest prime factor assigned to it 
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Then I use this array to divide given number to prime factors

```
    public static long[] intoPrimeFactors (long n){
        long[] array = new long[range-1];

        while(!isPrime(n)){
            array[a]=Sieve[(int)n];  //here's an error
            n/=Sieve[(int) n];
            a++;
        }
        array[a]=n;

        return array;


    }
```

At the main I'm printig out all of the factors

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long n=new Long(args[0]);
        init(Math.abs(n));
        long[] array = intoPrimeFactors(Math.abs(n)); //here's an error
        System.out.print(n+" = ");

        if(n<0){
            n=Math.abs(n);
            System.out.print("-1*");
        }

        for(int i=0;i<=a;i++){
            if(i!=a)System.out.print(array[i]+"*");
            else System.out.print(array[i]);
        }

    }
```

And it works just fine on small numbers (int) but when I type in something like 9223371331 I get ArrayOutOfBound error (in functions main and intoPrimeFactors) and I'm not really sure why. Could you help me ?

Comment: You may need to use BigInteger http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: You're taking a `long` and casting to an `int`.  You shouldn't count on anything after that point.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you initialized `Sieve`:

```
protected final static int[] Sieve = new int[(int) Math.pow(2,PowOf2)];
```

Its size is: 2097152

Then in `intoPrimeFactors`,
this code will be executed for the number you give as input:

```
while(!isPrime(n)){
    array[a]=Sieve[(int)n];  //here's an error
    n/=Sieve[(int) n];
    a++;
}
```

With large enough non-prime input, this will attempt to access beyond the capacity of `Sieve`, resulting in a `ArrayOutOfBound`. The error message in the exception also tells you the exact index that was too big for `Sieve`.

So what can you do? First of all there is something you cannot do, which is this:

```
Sieve[(int) n]
```

If `n` is too big, the value will overflow, and you will get a different index from the one you intended, a wrong index. I guess you did this cast to fix a compiler error, but it doesn't make sense. Using a `long` variable as an array index, casted to an `int` can only work if the value is actually within the range of an `int`. In which case the index variable should be declared as an `int`, not as a `long` in the first place. But that's not your case, as you want to support very large numbers.

But even if you could use a `long` as the array index, would your computer have enough memory to contain such a large array? I doubt that. If you want to use such a large sieve, you would need to create a custom data type such that:

- it allows long indexes
- it stores data somewhere else (probably on disk) when it doesn't fit in memory

Or you can calculate the prime factors without using a sieve. See this other answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252237/641955

Comment: thanks! But what's the solution ? I can't change capacity of Sieve, I can change its type to long but it doesn't help me with the errors

Comment: I added more explanation, and an alternative solution, see my update

Comment: @no, thank you. I handle big numbers by manually looking for prime factors. Something like

Comment: if(!prime(Bignumber)){ while(Bignumber%n!=0) n++; Bignumber/=n; }